# VScode Configuration

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm just trying to find out how to configure VScode to design my code in a certain way,
I just changed my computer and I can't seem to find out the property to set that will change my code from this :

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text("data",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),),);
  }
}
```

To this :

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        "Dara",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This used to work for me in my old pc just by hitting CTRL+S.

Comment: enable a formatter on Save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Flutter extension from VS code Market place.

If you want to format automatically whenever you save a file, set the **editor.formatOnSave** setting to **true** in VS code.

Comment: I tried to give you but this thing pop-up :Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.